# Unicode character that lines up with ⎮ but is as long as ⎢

Tags: unicode

Sorry if this isn't the right overflow for this question.  I need a unicode character that is as long as ⎢ (23A2, LEFT SQUARE BRACKET EXTENSION) but lines up horizontally with ⎮ (23AE, INTEGRAL EXTENSION).  Is there such a character?

Comment: Character widths are going to depend on the font, not just the code point.

Comment: I'm not concerned about width, just alignment.

Comment: What are the \u values of the 2 chars you're using in your question?

Comment: @S.Jones, Sorry, I was a little lazy when I first posted.  I have edited with the code points.

Comment: Interesting, those chars causes an extreme large "invisible padding" around the text in Firefox.

Comment: "as long as".. do you mean "takes up as much horizontal space" or "the black part extends the same distance from top to bottom"?

Comment: I am talking about the vertical length of the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this does depend on the font.  If I use DejaVu Sans Mono, INTEGRAL EXTENSION is as long as I want it to be.  This font appears to be almost exactly the same as the font I was using, Menlo, except for some small differences with some characters (including this one).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com). If you draw a straight line, it shows plenty of different codepoints resembling |.

As already pointed out, exact placement and size may depend on the font, but if you know that the font is going to be a specific one (because you supply it), you could still find the character you're looking for.